# Format Date ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have a date string in the format `2015-03-09T11:09:00.000Z`. How do I convert this to `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

I tried,

```
require 'date'
string = "2015-03-09T11:09:00.000Z"
date = Date.strptime(string,"%Y%m%d")
```

It gives,
`ArgumentError: invalid date`.

I want the following output `"2015-03-09"`

Can anyone show me some direction in this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that, in future, you refrain from thanking everyone for their answer. It's just clutter. Moreover, you shouldn't express your appreciation for poor or incorrect answers, but if you don't thank one out of five giving answers, the missing thank you will stick out like a sore thumb. You'll see that SO members tend to restrict their gratitude to truly exceptional answers. Lastly, members are not expecting to be thanked.

Answer (score 2):

You did it almost right. Just made a little mistake in specifying the date format. You just need to change: `"%Y%m%d"` to: `"%Y-%m-%d"`. Then, it will work!

```
require 'date'
string = "2015-03-09T11:09:00.000Z"
Date.strptime(string,"%Y-%m-%d").to_s
# > "2015-03-09"
```

To see all the available date formats, look at the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class).

> How do I convert this to yyyy-mm-dd format?

As the above documentation shows, you can use `'%Y-%m-%d'` format which will work like your desired `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a string, and not a date object, all you need is:

```
string[0,10] #=> "2015-03-09"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
require 'date'
string = "2015-03-09T11:09:00.000Z"
date = Date.strptime(string,"%Y-%m-%d").to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is in Time so I would use Time to parse the string and format it to date.

```
string = "2015-03-09T11:09:00.000Z"
date = Time.parse(string).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The output is `"2015-03-09"`. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's interesting, considering that `Time.methods.include?(:parse) #=> false`.